# What else can I try to debug a "ModuleNotFoundError" in Django?

Tags: django, module

I’m having problems with one module in my Visual Studio Core project.  It is not being found.  It generates this error:

File "C:\Users\danj\source\repos\project_django\comstockapt\comstockapt\urls.py", line 28, in 
from comstockapt.email_accounts import views as email_views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'comstockapt.email_accounts'

I’ve gone through many, many similar questions, but I can’t get it to work.  I’m using the virtual environment.  When I execute “python” in the terminal and then run ‘help(“modules email_accounts”)’ it shows the module with all of its files.
When I run help(“modules”), I see all of my modules listed in the response.

Here is my urls.py file within module comstockapt.comstockapt.

[image]

Here is my installed_apps:
[image]

I've checked environment variables, the virtual environment,  the directory structure.  What can I try next?

Comment: Please do not include screenshot of your code but paste it and format it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import views from email_accounts like this:

```
from email_accounts import views as email_views
```

Comment: This worked after fixing a few other modules with the same issue.  VS Code marks them with 'Import "email_accounts" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)'.  It looks like a syntax problem which does not go away until adding comstockapt in front of it - comstockapt.email_accounts.